# Error when I try to build Android app with CNTK by Unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, cntk

I have try so many weeks for build a Android app with CNTK's CNN evaluation function(C#) by Unity. But I encountered some error that I don't know how to solve.

The processing pipeline I expect is:

1. Train the model using Keras (by python)
2. Convert model to CNTK's format
3. Use CNTK(C#)'s Evaluation function in Unity
4. Export Android APK

I successed use CNTK for evaluation an image when I just use Play button in Unity before I builded. But when it has installed in my Android phone, it showed some error like CNTK cannot initialize because it cannot find the CPU.

The error message is below:

### [error message screenshot threw on cellphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LavZb.png)

my system Configuration:

- OS : Win10
- Unity : 2017.3
- Script Backend : Mono (I try IL2CPP but get some error)
- API Compatibility : .NET 4.6
- Build System : Gradle
- CNTK 2.4 (C#)

(I also export to android studio and use AVD (arm processor) and failed.)

### [and give my project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCm6v.png)

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/826

Comment: Hi, I would like to know what you did to overcome this challenge. I have also tried multiple way to do supervised learning inference with Unity, using frozen graph from models trained on keras (tensorflow backend). But is seems to be very complicated. The ml-agents, unity inference, barracuda, tensorflowsharp aren't working well. So, I plan to use Android studio and focus on tensorflow mobile tensorflow lite.

Answer (score 0):

CNTK doesn't support ARM CPU now. https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/266